# PHP - Syntax error when using ternary operator

Tags: php

Need to add the selected attribute to the matching condition. I'm passing the $fetch_state_db as the function parameter which is getting as expected. Please let me know where is the syntax error.

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
> Type: ParseError
> Message: syntax error, unexpected '' value="'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

```
  $output = '<option value="">Select State</option>';
  foreach($query->result() as $row)
  {
    $output .= '<option '($row->id==$fetch_state_db)?'selected="selected"':''' value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->region.'</option>';
  }
  return $output;
```

Comment: You missed the `.` before the ternary operator

Comment: I've sometimes found when using the ternary inside strings you also need to wrap the whole thing in brackets  '<option ' . ($row->id==$fetch_state_db ? 'selected="selected" ' : '' )'

Comment: Thanks for all the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler to read and maintain if you dont try and crush everything into the one line. And also if you use `"` so the variables will auto expand, and use `'` quote to wrap the html element attributes.

```
$output = '<option value="">Select State</option>';
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    $sel = $row->id==$fetch_state_db ? "selected='selected'" : '';
    $output .= "<option $sel value='{$row->id}'>{$row->region}</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code should be:

```
$output .= '<option '. ($row->id==$fetch_state_db)?'selected="selected"':''. ' value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->region.'</option>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Getting the same error after adding dot.

Comment: There is another `.` missing after the ternary ooerator

Answer (score 1):

Easier to read

```
    $output = '<option value="">Select State</option>';
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $selected =  $row->id== $fetch_state_db ? 'selected="selected"':"" ;
        $output .= '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->region.'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many single quotes (') in the second part of you ternary.

Try using double quotes instead of single. In my opinion I think it's a little more readable.

```php
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
   $output .= "<option " . ($row->id == $fetch_state_db ? 'selected="selected"' : "") . " value=\"$row->id\">$row->region</option>";
}
return $output;
```

Comment: this still won't work will it? due to the missing concatenation before the brackets

Comment: you've also closed it in the wrong place, as now you're saying only show the value if it's not selected

Comment: Well this is embarrassing.

Comment: And also to me as well lol. I fixed it again, thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

Well it is issue of concatenation. Use the following

```
output .= '<option '.($row->id==$fetch_state_db ?'selected="selected"':''' ).' value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->region.'</option>';
  }
```

Sorry i am using mobile.